# How to bind behavior on newly inserted Dom elements?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In my website I have buttons that are loaded via AJAX. How can I ensure that my jQuery `hide()` operation is applied to all buttons that are inserted into the DOM in future? 
As far as I know `on()` works only when you register events like click for example.

```
<button class="myButtton">Button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".myButton").hide();
```

Comment: I don't understand what the last sentence has to do with the question, but make sure to quote your selector: `$(".myButton").hide();` Also you can use .hide() on the elements before they're inserted, if you want to. Wrap the in jQuery, `.hide()` and `.appendTo()` or similar.

Comment: Why don't you call `$(".myButton").hide();` after you insert the new elements...

Comment: Because I do not wont to load JQuery conten in my Ajax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.myButton {
  display: none;
}
```

While adding the content apply  `myButton`  class to the element

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery function .on()
This will apply the behavior also to element that are added to the dom later.

```
$(document).on('click','.elementClass' , function(e){
     // do something
});
```

Comment: I wrote that I do not want to bind a click event. I want to bind after insert into the dom a function like hide()

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just use css to have a hidden button upon being inserted. jQuery.hide() is basically in css display: none. http://api.jquery.com/hide/.

```
.myButton {
  display: none;
}
```

Then when you are ready to show it just use $(".myButton").show(); aka [display: block](http://api.jquery.com/show/).